# caffe:how to concat two blobs after ImageData Layers

Tags: concatenation, caffe

I am trying to detect changed pixels from two images which are took in different time at the same place, so I used slice window to get 5x5 patches for every pixel in two images.

After that, I got 45000 patches for each image, and I selected 35000 patches randomly for training and the others for testing (two images use the same selection).

Then I stored in `train/train1` and `train/train2`, `val/val1` and `val/val2`.

The `train1.txt` looks like `path/to/train/train1/1_00001.png 0`,`train2.txt looks like path/to/train/train2/2_00001.png 0`,
`1_00001` and `2_00001` are corresponding pixels in two images, and `label=0` means unchanged, `label=1` means changed, `val1.txt` and `val2.txt` are similar.

Instead of converting into lmdb or leveldb, I used ImageData Layer directly, after `DataLayer`,I aimed to concat two blobs in channel(the two images are single channel), so my `train_val.prototxt` is:

```
name: "ChangeDetec"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "data/changedetec/train1.txt"
    batch_size: 500
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pair_data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "pair_data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "data/changedetec/train2.txt"
    batch_size: 500
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "data/changedetec/val1.txt"
    batch_size: 1000
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pair_data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "pair_data"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "data/changedetec/val2.txt"
    batch_size: 1000
  }
}
layer {
  name: "channelconcat"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "para_data"
  top: "concatdata"
}
layer {
  name: "conv1/5x5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "concatdata"
  top: "conv1/5x5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1/relu_5x5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1/5x5"
  top: "conv1/5x5"
}
layer {
  name: "conv2/1x1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1/5x5"
  top: "conv2/1x1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2/relu_1x1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2/1x1"
  top: "conv2/1x1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3/1x1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv2/1x1"
  top: "conv3/1x1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3/relu"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3/1x1"
  top: "conv3/1x1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4/1x1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3/1x1"
  top: "conv4/1x1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv4/relu"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4/1x1"
  top: "conv4/1x1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5/1x1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4/1x1"
  top: "conv5/1x1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv5/relu"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5/1x1"
  top: "conv5/1x1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv6/1x1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv5/1x1"
  top: "conv6/1x1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 4
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6/relu"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv6/1x1"
  top: "conv6/1x1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv7/1x1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv6/1x1"
  top: "conv7/1x1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7/relu"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv7/1x1"
  top: "conv7/1x1"
}
layers {
  name: "pool"
  bottom: "conv7/1x1"
  top: "pool"
  type: "Pooling"
  pooling_param {
    pool: AVE
    kernel_size: 1
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "pool"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layers {
  name: "loss"
  type: SoftmaxWithLoss
  bottom: "pool"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  include: { phase: TRAIN }
}
```

and solver.prototxt is:

```
net: "examples/changedetec/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 500
test_interval: 500
base_lr: 0.001
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 5000
snapshot_prefix: "examples/changedetec/changedetec_train"
solver_mode: GPU
```

But I got the error:

```
I0812 10:33:31.980985  3846 solver.cpp:91] Creating training net from    net file: examples/changedetec/train_val.prototxt
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 11:11: Expected double.
F0812 10:33:31.981097  3846 upgrade_proto.cpp:79] Check failed:   ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file:  examples/changedetec/train_val.prototxt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f148e770daa  (unknown)
    @     0x7f148e770ce4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f148e7706e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7f148e773687  (unknown)
    @     0x7f148eecae3e  caffe::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie()
    @     0x7f148eedf17b  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7f148eee024c  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7f148eee057a  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @     0x7f148eea2043  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
    @           0x40ed1e  caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
    @           0x407ec2  train()
    @           0x405cbc  main
    @     0x7f148d2cdf45  (unknown)
    @           0x40648d  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What's wrong in my prototxts or is there something I did wrong?Has there a better way to tackle this problem?This has bothering me so many days,please help me.

update in Aug23

I have fixed some low-level errors and still get some other errors:

1. I commented  `scale:0.00390625` because the error says `Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 11:11: Expected double.`.
2. Then the original error has been fixed,but the error jumped to `Pooling layer`,sayed `Expected integer or identifier`,so I commented `Pooling layer`and changed the last `Convolution layer` and `ReLU layer`'s num_output to 2 when I use `SoftmaxWithLoss layer`,but the error is the same as `Pooling layer`except it happened in `SoftmaxWithLoss layer`.
3. I tried `SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss` with the last `Convolution layer` and `ReLU layer`'s num_output is 1 but it makes no difference to the matter .
4. I also convert images into LMDB，but error just as well as 1-3 above.

Comment: the error message you get says there is something wrong on line 11 column 11… the parser expects numeric value there. check that you are reading the correct file and that there are no hidden characters there

Comment: @Shai Yes,thank you for your mention . I have found that low-level error and I have correct it,now I have edit my changes in post ,but I met other error